# How to get a list of variable dependencies in r script

Tags: r, dependencies

Is there a way to get a list of variable dependencies in an R script after it has run? For example, suppose we have a simple script

```
dog <- 3
mouse <- 1:10
cat <- dog * mouse
```

If we clear the memory before running the script, and then run the script,

```
model.vars <- ls()
```

gives

```
model.vars =
    [1] "cat"   "dog"   "mouse"
```

Now, given this list, how can we create a list of the variable dependencies for each variable, something that returns a result similar to

```
my.var.list =
    $cat = “dog", “mouse”
    $dog = NULL
    $mouse = NULL
```

Comment: What would happen if the script weren't as "simple"? What if there were functions and conditional structures and user input? In general, this does not sound like an easy problem to solve with all the different language features R offers. What problem are you *really* trying to solve?

Comment: Good question. First, there very well could be complex dependencies, but I'll try to deal with that later. Of course code that is useful for what I want to do will be more complicated than my simple example, but for now, let's assume I write code that doesn't use all the complex possibilities that can occur. Second, what I want to do ultimately is to create a list of dependencies so that I can create an influence diagram of my R code. I've already created the script that does this given that I have a list of the variable dependencies, but the missing piece is the code that generates the list.

Comment: So what exactly are we to assume then? Please clearly state the set of possible inputs. Then it might be able to possible to parse the R code for a very limited set of instructions to determine dependencies. But without a clear list of what can be assumed, this hasn't simplified the problem at all.

Comment: My hope is that there is an underlying variable registry in R that can be accessed, and that registry contains not only the variables in memory, but the parent-child relationships of the variables.

Comment: No. R does not store that. Dependencies aren’t preserved, they are evaluated then forgotten. You’d need to do a code analysis to determine/infer dependencies. The run-time will not do that for you.

Comment: Ok. Thank you, @MrFlick.